# Get asterisk after placeholder text in All Required field

Tags: magento2, css, placeholder, field

I want to add an asterisk mark to placeholder of inputs. Something like this: 
[image]

```
<input type="text" name="your-name" placeholder="Naam">
```

***I do not want to add the symbol directly in the placeholder.***

Currently trying to add pleaceholder after css but that is not working.

```
input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
   content: '*';
   color: red;
}
```

anyone can help me add an asterisk to the placeholder.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm also want to do this but not sure where to update. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily with jQuery
Put the following code in footer.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var content = jQuery('input:text').attr('placeholder');
  jQuery('input:text').attr('placeholder',content+'*');
});
```

Comment: Do I need to put this code in footer.phtml, right?

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="cc-contorlitem">
  <div class="cc-placeholder">
     <label class="cc-lbl">Description</label><span class="cc-req">*</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="cc-name cc-inputcontrol" value="" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" required>
</div>

css
.cc-contorlitem {
  position: relative;
}
.cc-placeholder {
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 10px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 32px;
      cursor: text;
      z-index: -1;
      .cc-lbl {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #07456b;
        font-family: helvetica;
        padding-right: 5px;
        cursor: text;
      }
      .cc-req {
        color: #f00;
      }
    }
    .cc-inputcontrol {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 35px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      outline: 0;
      box-shadow: none;
      appearance: none;
      border: 1px solid #717171;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #07456b;

}
.cc-inputcontrol:not(:focus) {
        background: transparent;
      }
.cc-inputcontrol:not(:focus):not([value=""]) {
          background: #fff;
        }
```